# Tableau concatenate fields that match a condition

Tags: tableau-api

I need to generate a label field by concatenating 5 fields, but here's the trick:  I only want to add strings that match a value, and not add null strings.  I have an example below where four fields are named "red, green blue and yellow"  The values can be "Y", "N", or "Null".   I need to build a label out of all of the "Y"  values:

```
Red, Green, Blue, Yellow
Y, N, Y, Null --> resultant string would be "Red, Blue"
Y, Y, Null, N --> resultant string would be "Red, Green"
N, Null, N, Y --> resultant string would be "Yellow"
```

What I've currently done is a cascading series of calculated fields where I check two fields, and put that in a temporary field, then I check the temporary field against the next column and make a new temporary field, etc. Like so (abbreviated code):

```
If Red is Y and Green is Y then Temp1 = "Red, Green"
Elsif Red is Y and Green <> Y  then Temp1 = "Red"
elsif Green is Y and Red <> Y then Temp1 = "Green"
Else Temp1 is 'empty'
```

The next calculation compares Temp1 to Blue for each condition and then builds temp2, and so on.

Question:  Is this the most efficient way to do it?  Or is there some clever code that I am missing?  Can I do it all in one calculation without an insane number of if/then combinations?  It would be nice to not have so many fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that concatenates based on the presence of "Y". In cases where the value is "N", Null, or something different,  the ELSE will add nothing to the concatenation.

```
//Calculated field you will create
REPLACE(TRIM( STR(IF [Red] = "Y" THEN "RED " ELSE "" END)+
STR(IF [Green] = "Y" THEN "Green " ELSE "" END)+
STR(IF [Blue] = "Y" THEN "Blue " ELSE "" END)+
STR(IF [Yellow] = "Y" THEN "Yellow" ELSE "" END)), " ", ", ")
```

The `TRIM()` removes any trailing spaces, which could appear if your last word was something other than 'Yellow". The `REPLACE()` that wraps around the whole statement adds a comma after each word -- replacing the space with a comma and a space.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!   I knew there had to be a way to do this.  I just couldn't seem to find the right keywords to look for the language in the references.    I'm going to reverse look-up your functions in the help reference to figure out where they are listed.    Sorry I couldn't upvote your answer, I am too new, apparently.

Comment: @EugeneCarroll you are able to accept the answer at any level. Click the checkmark below the up/downvote arrows if this solves it for you.